# How can I reference component properties from within an *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have an ngFor where I'm yielding mat-list-items and I need to construct a url from a proeprty that's defined on the containing component like so:

```
<mat-list *ngIf="element == expandedRow">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let recording of element.callRecordings;index as i">
        <h4 matLine style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold;">Recording {{i + 1}}</h4>
        <p matLine>
            <mat-basic-audio-player [audioUrl]="callRecordingsUrlRoot + recording.fileName" [displayTitle]="false">
            </mat-basic-audio-player>
        </p>
        <a matLine [href]="callRecordingsUrlRoot + recording.fileName">Download</a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

`callRecordingsUrlRoot` is a property defined on the component but when referenced from within the ngFor, it's unavailable.

How can I go about getting retrieving its value?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your component's `.ts` file as well? Your HTML template looks ok.

Comment: Actually it turns out I'm just an idiot